# Adding delay in packets using DPDK

Tags: networking, latency, dpdk

I want to simulate latency in packets I send using DPDK.

Initially I added usleep(10), and it worked but later I realized using sleep might hinder performance of my traffic generator.

```
usleep(10);
rte_eth_tx_burst(m_repid, queue_id, tx_pkts, nb_pkts);
```

So, I tried using a polling mechanism. Something like this:

```
inline void add_latency(float lat) {
    //usleep(lat);
    float start = now_sec();
    float elapsed;
    do {
        elapsed = now_sec() - start;
    } while(elapsed < (lat/1000));
}
```

But the packets are not getting send.
tx_pkts: 0

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

DPDK version:  DPDK 22.03

Firmware:

```
# dmidecode -s bios-version
2.0.19
```

NIC:

```
0000:01:00.0 'I350 Gigabit Network Connection' if=em1 drv=igb unused=igb_uio,vfio-pci,uio_pci_generic *Active*
0000:01:00.3 'I350 Gigabit Network Connection' if=em4 drv=igb unused=igb_uio,vfio-pci,uio_pci_generic
```

Comment: please update with DPDK version, NIC, firmware, and whether you are using low-latency mode for TX burst )supported on limited NIC) or not. Also please note adding delay before `rte_eth_tx_burst` is not a right approach too. For more details, you will need to update the question with dpdk version, nic and firmware.

Comment: Hi @VipinVarghese thanks a lot! So for this low latency mode I will need either intelE810 or intel X710? I have another setup with Mellanox NIC CX-5. Can I add support there?

Comment: with Intel NIC for low latency as I recollect you need to compile and pass option (for E810). With respect to mellanox which is the nic card in question?

Comment: These are the mellanox nic:

0000:00:07.0 'MT27800 Family [ConnectX-5]' drv=mlx5_core unused=igb_uio,vfio-pci,uio_pci_generic

Comment: I have updated with the answer, please go through the same. If you find this useful please accept and upvot to close the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both Intel NIC i350 and Mellanox MT27800 as per `DPDK 22.03` does not support HW offload for `delayed packet transmission`. Delayed packet transmission is a hardware feature which allows transmission of a packet at a defined future timestamp. For example if one needs to send a packet 10 microseconds from time of DMA to NIC buffer, the TX descriptor can be updated with the `10us` as TX timestamp.

A similar (approximate) behaviour can be achieved by enabling `TX timestamp` on HW by Reporting back the timestamp in the transmit descriptor. The timestamp captured will be the time at which the first byte of the packet is sent out on the wire. With an approximation of time required for DMA of the packet from DPDK Main memory to NIC SRAM one can achieve the `delayed packet transmit`.

But there are certain caveats for the same, such as

1. DPDK NIC pmd should support low latency mode (allow tx of 1 packet burst). Example Intel E810 nic PMD args
2. Allow disabling of HW Switch engine and lookup. Example vswitch_disable or eswitch_disbale in the case of Mellanox CX-5 and CX-6 nic.
3. Support for HW TX time stamps to allow software control on TX intervals.

note:

1. Intel i210 in Linux driver supports delayed transmission with help TX shaper.
2. With Mellanox NIC `ConnectX-7` using PMD arg `tx_pp`can be used to capability to schedule traffic directly on timestamp specified in descriptor is provided.
3. Since the question is not clarified for `packet size, Inter Frame Gap delay` for `simulate latency in packets I send using DPDK`, the assumption is made it on the wire for 64B with fixed default IFG.

Suggestion:

Option-1: if it is 64B best approach is to create an array of pause packets for TX burst. Select the time intervals based on HW or SW timestamp to swap the array index with the actual packet intended to be sent.

Option-2: allow synce packets to synchronize the time stamps between server-client. Using out of band information do dynamic sleep (with approximate cost for DMA and wire transfer) to skew to desired results.

***Please note if the intention is check the latency on DUT the whole approach is specified as code snippet is not correct. Refer DPDK synce example or DPDK pktgen latency for more clarity.***